# Strong branching

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, branch-and-bound

Within B&B when it comes to select variables to branch on, I can use the concept of "strong branching". The optimizer, in my case CPLEX, then performs branching on variables it selects.

Is it possible, to allow the user to select the candidate list for strong branching at least at the root node?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that option is explicitly supported in CPLEX. There might be a workaround, assuming you knew your candidate list before you started solving. (Warning: I'm speculating here.) You could try assigning a priority order to the integer variables, giving variables on your candidate list a priority of 1 and variables not on the list a priority of zero. Then set the variable selection parameter to strong branching and the node limit to 1 (if you want to stop at the root node) or something larger (if you want to restrict to your candidate list for a while). Once the solver hits the node limit, delete the priorities, remove the node limit and call solve() again. Since you made no changes to the model, the solver should resume from the partial tree left by the initial run. I'm not positive that priorities trump strong branching and that strong branching is used to break priority ties, but it seems plausible.